# flags: import parameter from yml file

Tags: r, keras

I'm trying the [flags function](https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/tools/training_flags.html), and I can not import the settings from a flags.yml file.

**flags.yml**

```
units1: 128
act1: sigmoid
dropout1: 0.4
units2: 1
act2: linear
dropout2: 0.3
```

**in console**

```
flag1 <- flags(file = "flags.yml")
flag1 
[1] name        type        value       description
<0 lignes> (ou 'row.names' de longueur nulle)
```

---

### inherits

```
flags_inherits <- flags(
  # flag_type(nom, valeur, description)
  flag_integer("units1", 10),
  flag_string("act1", "linear"),
  flag_numeric("dropout1", 1),
  flag_integer("units2", 1),
  flag_string("act2", "linear"),
  flag_numeric("dropout2", 1),
  file = "flags_inherits.yml",
  config = "alt2"
)
```

Error: The following flags were provided but not declared: inherits

**flags_inherits.yml**

```
alt1:
  units1: 128
  units2: 1

alt2:
  inherits: alt1
  act1: sigmoid
  dropout1: 0.4
  act2: linear
  dropout2: 0.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Like in the example, the `flags()` function expects you to define the flags you actually want to read. It doesn't just read all possible values. For example, with your data

```
FLAGS <- flags(
  flag_integer("units1", 128),
  flag_string("act1", "sigmoid"),
  flag_numeric("dropout1", 0.4),
  flag_integer("units2", 1),
  flag_string("act2", "linear"),
  flag_numeric("dropout2", 0.3),
  file="flags.yml"
)
```

If you just want to read values from the yaml file into a list, you can use

```
yaml::yaml.load_file("flags.yml")
```

Comment: Hello, i understood. I try flags that has named configurations which inherit from each other but i get a error: **Error: The following flags were provided but not declared: inherits** ( I edited my post ).

Comment: @problème0123 is there some guide or documentation you are following that makes you believe “inherits” is a special property that you can use without declaring?

Comment: hello, i follow this guide [Training Flags](https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/tools/training_flags.html)